# Is there a database modeling library for PHP that I can use as third party that supports generating models from tables?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, model, code-generation

I have an old php project that is written procedural. I'm looking for a library that can generate models from mysql database tables, so that I can use them as objects in the code and avoid lots of repeating. Something similar to ActiveRecord modeling classes found in modern PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doctrine 1.2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/index.html), [Doctrine2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/index.html) (with the [CodeGenerator project](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineCodeGenerator)). I think [Propel](http://propelorm.org/documentation/#project_setup) still supports this as well.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to integrate Propel in to that project. Not sure why is this marked as not constructive, cause I have a concrete question that can be only answered correctly or not, in no relation to personal opinion.